# Showing that the log is the inverse of the exponential

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

I know this question may seem easy however I am not "meant" to know any facts about log other than it is defined by $L=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt$ and that the exponential function is given by the usual sum.

To start with I composed $L \circ E $ which fell out to get $x$ which is what I wanted. However I am struggling with the other way: $E \circ L $. So far I have that:

$$E \circ L =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt)^n}{n!}$$

But I cannot see any obvious way to show this is equal to $x$ for $x\gt0$. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: *Hint*: $$\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt)^n}{n!}\right)' = \frac{1}{x} \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}dt)^n}{n!}\right)$$

Comment: @macton This is I was thinking as well. OP: your sum should start at $0$, not $1$,  for what it's worth.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ahhh thank you will change

Comment: @macton I think that I want to show that this derivative is now equal to 1, so I would need the bracketed thing to be $x$ to cancel. However I am not allowed to use the integral of that function so not  sure what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

*Same idea as @macton and @CameronWilliams.*

We will define $$F=E\circ L=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]^n.$$
We want to take the derivative of $F(x)$. Note that the Mc-Laurin series of the exponential function converges (absolutely) for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. That means that we can interchange derivative and summation.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right]^n.$$
We derived to the last step by using the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus. Note that this series is equal to $F(x)$. So we may rewrite
$$F'(x)=\frac{1}{x}F(x).$$
This leads to an easy differential equation, with the solution $F(x)=x$.
That means that
$$E\circ L=x,$$
so we have proven that $L$ is the inverse function of $E$.